# Elastic Search unresponsive after logstash-* index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Kibana defaults to searching logstash-*, which causes my elastic search instance to become unresponsive. It spits out a ton of the below messages. I don't use this index for Kibana, so I can use it fine so long as no one ends up hitting the settings button which defaults to searching logstash-*. Any hints at what might be causing it to become unresponsive and how to fix it? Timing out would be fine if the elastic search server still continued to accept logs and recover.

```
[2017-02-01 04:10:00,448][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Axum] [logstash-2016.11.10][2], node[1H3yc3QBSUqAzkJb6S8cTA], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org$
org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsRejectedExecutionException: rejected execution (queue capacity 1000) on org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTr$
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsAbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(EsAbortPolicy.java:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
```

Comment: Have a look at following [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html#modules-threadpool)

Comment: you can always change the default index in kibana by going into settings and changing it there.  you can also remove the logstash-* index from being accessible from kibana.  It doesn't explain the underlying issue though.